# Bootstrab tr class="info" with version 3.3.7 still doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm using Bootstrap version 3.3.7 with virtual studio 2015. the problem is when i want use Contextual Classes table it shows all the rows color except the Blue color 'info'. 
Now i try to update but it shows  3.3.7 is the last version package.
Any one can help to fix that.

```
   <tr class="success">
    <td>Success</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="danger">
    <td>Danger</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td>Info</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
  </tr>
```

this is just example from my code.

Comment: Seems to work fine with 3.3.7: http://www.bootply.com/PXTQ9ReHX4

Answer (score 1):

To get what you want you need to set `class="table"` for table:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table">
<tr class="success">
    <td>Success</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>john@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="danger">
    <td>Danger</td>
    <td>Moe</td>
    <td>mary@example.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="info">
    <td>Info</td>
    <td>Dooley</td>
    <td>july@example.com</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is my code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr class="active">
            <th>Activtät</th>
            <th>Läuft?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="info">
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.systemtyp)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.systemtyp)</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="info">
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CadWorkerlauftstartet)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CadWorkerlauftstartet)</td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="danger">
            <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PublizierWarteschlangeuberprufen)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PublizierWarteschlangeuberprufen)</td>

        </tr>
```

[The photo shows  ,  are working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgfAo.png)

Comment: I think some css rule overrides bootstrap style in your page. Could you give a link to your page?

Comment: You should edit your question to provide this info instead of posting your code as an answer.